# Comparing field data with another table

Tags: php, mysql

After reading and finding online, I still do not have any idea how to solve my problem. And there's no way that I can do like this:

```
$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list categories where id='3'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

echo "whatever fields that I want to display onto the form before category field";

$select=mysql_query("select * from categories ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){

echo "compare with the result in categories table and select the option if it's true";

}
}
```

Am I right?

Currently I have 2 tables in database products_list and categories.

Table products_list consist of many fields:
ID, code, price, category, status, etc...

Table categories only have:
ID, category (where this table only contains all the available set of category options)

I have an update/edit form which I use the select statement and get all the results from Table products_list that the user previously saved all their data.

Under the category part on the form itself is a multiple selection listbox.

My problem now is:

1. Display all the result from Table products_list onto the update/edit form
2. Display all the category options from Table categories onto the update/edit form (listbox)
3. Comparing the category that is saved by the user in Table products_list and select the options that is display on the listbox (which is no.2 question)

I really need a lot of help on this as I have never done this before and don't know what's going on reading those articles or threads online. Hope you guys understand my question. Thanks in advance.

Currently updated codings but still stuck:

```
$result2= mysql_query("SELECT category FROM categories ORDER BY id ");
$all_cat = array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) { 
    $all_cat[] = $row2['category'];
}

//dropdownlist query
$query="SELECT * from products_list where id='100'";
$result = mysql_query ($query);

//populate the dropdownlist

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

  $sel_cats = explode(",", $row['category']);
  //determine if the category is selected
  foreach ($sel_cats as $sel_cat){

  $selected = '';

  if ($sel_cat == $all_cat ){
           $selected =' selected="selected" ';
           break;
        }

  }

    foreach($all_cat as $i => $value)
    {
     echo  '<option value="' . $value. '"' . $selected . '>'.$value.'</option>\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: The code that I pasted is a rough idea, not the actual one.

Comment: Hi Sel, I have tried and edit your codes but am stuck again. Currently it is able to display all the options that is from categories table but the selected function from products_list table isn't working.

Comment: It's ok, I solved it already but no idea is it the best way. I shifted the foreach sel_cat into the foreach all_cat and changed the if $sel_cat == ($all_cat) to $value. Thanks a lot for helping me to get to here, appreciated. =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get all product, assuming the saved category is cat column in product_list table
$result2= mysql_query("SELECT * from products_list where id='3'");
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$sel_cat =$row2['cat'];

//dropdownlist query
$query="SELECT cat,id FROM categories ORDER BY id ";
$result = mysql_query ($query);


//populate the dropdownlist
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      //determine if the category is selected
      $selected = ($row['id '] == $sel_cat ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : NULL;
      echo  '<option value="' . $row['id']. '"' . $selected . '>'.$row['cat'].'</option>\n';
}
```

For category saved in concatenated string format. eg: black,white,red

```
 // get all product, assuming the saved category is cat column in product_list table
    $result2= mysql_query("SELECT * from products_list where id='3'");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $sel_cats = explode(',', $row2['cat']);

    //dropdownlist query
    $query="SELECT cat,id FROM categories ORDER BY id ";
    $result = mysql_query ($query);


    //populate the dropdownlist
    echo '<select name="cat" size="5" multiple="multiple">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
          //loop thru the sel_cat
           foreach ($sel_cats as $sel_cat){
          //determine if the category is selected
           $selected = '';
           if ($row['id '] == $sel_cat ){
               $selected =' selected="selected" ';
               break;
           }
          }
          echo  '<option value="' . $row['id']. '"' . $selected . '>'.$row['cat'].'</option>\n';

    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Finally!! Thanks for the help. I will try this out whether it works. =x

Comment: Hi Sel, I have tried out your code. It did return me all the results from the table categories but it's not selected with the data from table products_list.

Comment: did you save the category id in the product list? or category name? in my example, i compare the saved id with categories id from categories table.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If I want to compare the name instead of the ID, is it possible? E.g: multiple values in category field from products_list compare with the category field regardless of how many entries from categories table?

Comment: of course you could compare with name. Just retrieve the category_name from products_list and compare. However, my example is based on 1 record returned. Not sure what do you meant by `multiple values in category field..regardless of how many entries...`

Comment: Retrieve id from products_list is here at `$sel_cat =$row2['cat'];`. The compare part is at `$selected = ($row['id '] == $sel_cat ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : NULL;` You could change accordingly.

Comment: Argh, my bad. I missed out the example again. In my products_list table I have ID 1 and a lot of column fields but 1 of the fields is category. So when user submits the form, it will save as e.g: Black White Blue under the category field of products_list table. And I use implode("\n", $_POST['category']) to save under that field column. As for the categories table, it is saved as ID 1 category Black, ID 2 category White, ID 3 category Blue and so on. Hmm.. Hope you roughly get my idea.

Comment: amended the answer for comma separated string. I think using `,` to separate the string would be more readable then using `\n`. you could change at `$sel_cats = explode(',', $row2['cat']);` to accommodate your reqd thou.

Comment: OH YES!! It worked!! Thanks alot for your help. But 1 last question, if I swap the result and result2 query, can it work? I just realised that i need to do my while loop for $result2 query instead of $result qery. =x

Answer (score 0):

use join sql query 
like 
eg,

```
select * from products_list, categories where product_list.id=categories.id ORDER  BY id ASC

 select * from products_list where id=1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But what if I want to display all the fields in products_list let's say 20 fields where ID=1 and I want to display all from categories table ORDER BY id ASC?

Comment: select * from products_list where id=1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I'm assuming that it is a simple Read statement.

1. Simply use PHP echo to display your query result to form.
2. Same with No. 1
3. To do comparison, one of many ways is to store your result (category) in a different variables. Lets say $userSelectedCategory and $listCategory (array), and then do a loop to $listCategory array items and comparing it to $userSelectedCategory.

What to do next is totally up to you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Because now I can only do the select statement for 1 table(products_list) display all the fields for that particular ID inside the while loop and the category field is somewhere in the middle of the while loop. So I have no idea how to get the results from the other table (categories) and compare. As like I said I can't put another select statement inside the select statement while loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select=mysql_query(" select * from products_list where id='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20 ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
$id = $row["id"]; 
echo $id;
}
```